# Active Directory Integration Plugin

Tags: php, ldap, centos6

I'm trying to integrate my Active directory to my website. So, I downloaded the AD Integration Plugin, but it says "ATTENTION: You have no LDAP support. This plugin won´t work. You must install or enable LDAP support in PHP."

How do I fix that? Is that a php problem?

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: In another plugin, Simple LDAP, I get this error Hello, I've install php5-ldap but I still can't get my Simple LDAP to work. It throws this error: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'adLDAPException' with message 'No LDAP support for PHP".

I've installed php5-ldap. It's supposed to be ok but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for your reference. I was able to solve my problem. It seems that when linux was installed to my server, ldap was not installed with it. So, what I did was I installed it following this link http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/viewp ... entos6.htm. After that, I compiled ldap to php. I followed this link: https://ma.ttias.be/how-to-compile-and- ... om-source/.